# Como ZIPAR somente imagens de uma pasta com PHP?

Tags: php, arquivo-zip

Galera, na minha pasta a ser zipada, há arquivos *`.php`* e *imagens*, mas preciso zipar **somente** as imagens!

Há está possibilidade com a [classe `ZipArchive`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) do PHP?

Minha função (*funciona perfeitamente pra tudo que está dentro da pasta*):

```
/* creates a compressed zip file */
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = 'revelacao/',$overwrite = false) {
    //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
    //vars
    $valid_files = array();
    //if files were passed in...
    if(is_array($files)) {
           //cycle through each file
           foreach($files as $file) {
               //make sure the file exists
               if(file_exists($file)) {
                   $valid_files[] = $file;
               }
            }
    }
    //if we have good files...
    if(count($valid_files)) {
           //create the archive
           $zip = new ZipArchive();
           if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
               return false;
           }

           //add the files
           foreach($valid_files as $file) {
               $new_filename = substr($file,strrpos($file,'/680') + 1);
               $zip->addFile($file,$new_filename);
           }

           //debug
           echo 'O zip contém ',$zip->numFiles,' status( 0 para ok e 1 para erro) : ',$zip->status;

           //close the zip -- done!
           $zip->close();

           //check to make sure the file exists
           return file_exists($destination);
    }
    else
    {
           return false;
    }
}
```

> **Atualização**: A variável `$file` que está dentro do `foreach`, não contem somente o nome e a extensão do arquivo e sim o caminho inteiro. Exemplo: *pasta1/subpasta1/foto.jpg*

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a função pathinfo()? Segue a doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: `$valid_files` seria uma filtragem? o `create_zip($files = array()` recebe "arquivos" ou "pastas"?

Comment: $valid_files verifica os arquivos válidos, ou seja, não pasta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se `$files` recebe os *arquivos com o caminho completo* e não a *pasta de onde irá obter os tais arquivos* em `create_zip($files`, então você pode filtrar o que é imagem pela extensão por exemplo:

```
if(is_array($files)) {
    //cycle through each file
    foreach($files as $file) {
        //make sure the file exists
        if(file_exists($file) &&
           (false !== strstr($file, '.jpg') || false !== strstr($file, '.jpeg') || false !== strstr($file, '.png') || false !== strstr($file, '.gif'))
        ) {
            $valid_files[] = $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Ou regex:

```
if(is_array($files)) {
    //cycle through each file
    foreach($files as $file) {
        //make sure the file exists
        if(file_exists($file) && preg_match('#\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$#', $file) > 0) {
            $valid_files[] = $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Ou usando [`finfo_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) (`finfo_*` é suportado a partir do PHP5.3):

> Note: Este exemplo com `finfo_*` é mais seguro que o `pathinfo` e os demais exemplos nesta resposta, conforme [Usar finfo ou pathinfo para pegar o mime type?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66109/3635)
>
> É necessário em alguns servidores habilitar `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` (windows) ou like-unix `extension=php_fileinfo.so`

```
function detectMimeType($file)
{
    $mime = '';
    if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mime  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
        $mime = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mime;
}

...

foreach($files as $file) {
    //make sure the file exists
    if(file_exists($file) && preg_match('#^image/#', detectMimeType($file)) > 0) {
        $valid_files[] = $file;
    }
}
```

Comment: O primeiro não funfou, trouxe os arquivos .php!

Comment: O regex não zipou!

Comment: O filnfo_open() não é suportado aqui.

Comment: sim, amigo!.....

Comment: O priemeiro zipou mas permitiu .php

Comment: Fiz um update na pergunta!

Comment: Ok, mas ele não identifica a extensão do arquivo na variável $file(no primeiro exemplo ), pois ela contem pastas e subpastas.

Comment: @Lollipop Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24180/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-lollipop).

Answer (score 4):

Segue uma outra alternativa, está tenta utilizar a [função `path_info`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php), se a função não existir, um outro meio é utilizado para recuperar a extensão do arquivo.

Os argumentos que a função recebe são:

1. `$arquivos`: **Exigido**. O *array* que conterá o caminho dos arquivos.
2. `$extensoes`: **Exigido**. O *array* que deve conter as extensões válidas para imagem por exemplo: `png`, `gif`, `jpg`, sem o `.`.
3. `$destino`: **Opcional**. O local de destino do *arquivo Zip*. O valor padrão é `Imagens.zip`, para colocá-lo num outro diretório (*nível abaixo da hierarquia*) faça `revelacao/Imagens.zip`.
4. `$sobrescrever`: **Opcional**. Se setado como *true*, sobrescreverá o *arquivo Zip* existente, o valor padrão é *false*.

Exemplo de utilização:

```
$arquivos = glob("*.*");                 // Captura todos os arquivos do diretório atual
$extensoes = array('gif', 'png', 'jpg'); // Extensões de imagens que você quer zipar

$resultado = create_zip($arquivos, $extensoes);
if ($resultado)
    echo "O arquivo ZIP foi criado com sucesso! \n";
else
    echo "Não foi possível criar o arquivo ZIP. \n";
```

Código:

```
function extrairExtensao($arquivo){
    if (function_exists('pathinfo')){
        $extensao = pathinfo($arquivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        return $extensao;
    } else {
        $partes = explode('.', $arquivo);
        $extensao = end($partes);
        return $extensao;
    }
}

function create_zip($arquivos = array(), $extensoes = array(), 
                    $destino = 'Imagens.zip', $sobrescrever = false) {
    if(file_exists($destino) &&  !$sobrescrever || 
       !is_array($arquivos) || !is_array($extensoes))
         return false;

    $arquivosValidos = array();

    foreach($arquivos as $arquivo) {
        $extensao = extrairExtensao($arquivo);
        if(file_exists($arquivo) && in_array($extensao, $extensoes))
            $arquivosValidos[] = $arquivo;      
    }

    if (count($arquivosValidos) == 0)
        return false;

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $bandeiras = $sobrescrever ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE;
    if($zip->open($destino, $bandeiras) !== true)
        return false;

    foreach($arquivosValidos as $arquivoValido) {
        $arquivo = basename($arquivoValido);
        $novoArquivo = substr($arquivo, strpos($arquivo, '/680') + 1);
        if ($zip->addFile($arquivo, $novoArquivo) !== true){
            echo "O arquivo {$arquivo} não pode ser adicionado ao ZIP. \n";
            // Encerrar a função aqui?
        }
    }

    echo "O ZIP contém " . $zip->numFiles . " arquivos. \n";
    echo "Status( 0 para OK e 1 para ERRO): " . $zip->status . "\n"; 
    $zip->close();
    return file_exists($destino);
}
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '[' in....($arquivo)['extension'];

Comment: @Lollipop Desculpe a intromissão, só uma tentativa de melhorar o código.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado pela edição!

Comment: Fiz um update na pergunta!