# Usar finfo ou pathinfo para pegar o mime type?

Tags: php, arquivo, mime-type

[`finfo_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.finfo.php) e [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) são usados para detectar o *mimetype* do arquivo e não a extensão.

A questão é que no mundo existem vários formatos de arquivos e de tempos em tempos aparecem novos formatos, não tenho como fazer um teste para saber qual função tem melhor suporte para detecção de mimetypes, ou seja é um teste inviável de se fazer devido a quantidade de formatos de arquivos, o que eu tenho duvida é sobre qual destas funções tem melhor suporte.

Questão:

- Qual destas funções tem melhor suporte para detectar os mime-types dos arquivos?
- Qual é melhor mantida pelo PHP?

Comment: O `pathinfo` é usado para obter informações sobre o **caminho de um arquivo**, já as funções `finfo_*` são usadas para obter informações **sobre o arquivo**. =) Então, o `pathinfo` não pega o *mime-type*, mas sim, a extensão. 1) Neste caso use `finfo_*`. 2) O `finfo_*` é suportado desde a versão *5.3.0* e o `pathinfo` *4.0.3*. Considere também o método [`getExtension`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/splfileinfo.getextension.php) da classe `SplFileInfo` a partir da *5.3.6* para obter a extensão. Para terminar, sobre o `finfo_*` veja [está página](https://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo).

Comment: @qmechanik KKkkkk viajei, pensei que `pathinfo` pegava o mimetype também

Comment: Formulei uma resposta. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambos são usados para **diferentes** propósitos.

As funções da [classe `finfo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.finfo.php) são utilizadas para obter informações sobre um determinado arquivo, por exemplo:

1. [`finfo_buffer`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.finfo-buffer.php): Está função é usada retornar a representação *textual* do valor especificado no argumento `string`.
2. [`finfo_file`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.finfo-file.php): Tem o mesmo propósito que a função `finfo_buffer`, porém está tem como finalidade obter informações de um arquivo.

   - ✞ [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mime-content-type.php): Está função é usada para detectar o [*Mime type*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) de um arquivo, porém ela foi **descontinuada** (PHP >= *4.3.0*, PHP *5*).

A [função `path_info`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php) por sua vez tem como finalidade retornar informações relativos ao **caminho do arquivo**, como:

- `PATHINFO_DIRNAME` O nome do diretório
- `PATHINFO_BASENAME` O nome do arquivo
- `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` A extensão do arquivo
- `PATHINFO_FILENAME` O nome do arquivo (sem a extensão - PHP >= *5.2.0*)

**Notas**:

- O [`Fileinfo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.fileinfo.php) vem habilitado por padrão desde o PHP 5.3.0, em versões anteriores, o `Fileinfo` era uma [extensão pecl](https://pecl.php.net/package/fileinfo), porém não é mais mantida (última atualização: *07-11-2006*).
- Segundo a página [introdutória](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.fileinfo.php), a capacidade de detecção do *Mime type* dependerá do seguinte fator:

  > As funções deste módulo tentam achar o tipo de conteúdo e codificação de um arquivo, procurando por *certas sequências de bytes mágicos em posições específicas dentro do arquivo*. Enquanto isto não é uma abordagem à prova de bala, a heurística utilizada faz um trabalho muito bom. Veja também:
  >   [Opções de configuração do *Mime type*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mime-magic.configuration.php).
- Uma outra forma de obter informações sobre um arquivo é usar as funções da [classe `SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.splfileinfo.php) ( a partir do PHP *5.1.2*).
- Uma outra alternativa é a [função `stat`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stat.php) (PHP *4*, PHP *5*).

Comment: Obrigado, acho que me confundi por causa da outra resposta, naquela pergunta sobre zip, foi pura distração minha rs. Muito obrigado!